# Android - API 23 - Not able to display incoming sms

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm trying to show on the screen the incoming sms. But nothing is happening when I send a new sms.

I'm using Nexus 5 (Api 23) emulator.

When debugging I got:

> Permission Denial: receiving Intent {act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone

In MainActivity.Java I deal with the permissions.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void getPermissionToReceiveSMS() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)) {
                // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
            }
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);
    }
}
```

**What Am I doing wrong? 
Could you help me out?**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.globa8track.gtw">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name=".gtwWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/gtw_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".smsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action." />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

smsReceiver.Java

```
package com.globa8track.gtw;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class smsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "Listener: incoming SMS.";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null){
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                for (SmsMessage message : messages){

                    String strMessageFrom = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String strMessageBody = message.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message received from:" +strMessageFrom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message content" +strMessageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //smsReceiver.class.getSmsDetails(strMessageFrom, strMessageBody);

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.globa8track.gtw;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Id to identify a read sms permission request
     *
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_SMS = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getPermissionToToast();
        getPermissionToReadSMSinbox();
        getPermissionToReceiveSMS();
    }

    // Called when the user is performing an action which requires the app to read the
    // sms inbox
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void getPermissionToReadSMSinbox() {
        // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
        // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
        // in Marshmallow
        // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
        // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // The permission is NOT already granted.
            // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
            // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
                    // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                    // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
                }
            }

            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},REQUEST_READ_SMS);
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void getPermissionToToast() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                    // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                    // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
                }
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void getPermissionToReceiveSMS() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)) {
                    // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                    // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
                }
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);
        }
    }



    // Callback with the request from calling requestPermissions(...)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_SMS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "READ_SMS permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "READ_SMS permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }


        if(requestCode == REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE){
            if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "READ_PHONE_STATE permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "READ_PHONE_STATE permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else{
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }


        if(requestCode == REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS){
            if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "RECEIVE_SMS permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "RECEIVE_SMS permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else{
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Remove the `Toasts` and use something else, like `Log` statements or breakpoints.

Comment: @CommonsWare tks for the reply, but why? Toast doesn't work in Api23?

Comment: `Toast` is fine. It is a lousy debugging tool, and I try to avoid it from places like `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare But Log is not only for debuging purposes? Which of the log should I use? Log.i ?

Comment: I think the point is to use debugging tools to first make sure you are even getting to the Toast statements. That way you don't have to say things like "I think it's because toast isn't working." You should KNOW what it is that isn't working, then work from there to solve that issue. You can't debug something if you don't even know what's broken to begin with.

Comment: I have changed the Toast To Log.i.  Log.i(TAG,"SMS Message received from:" +strMessageFrom);` and `Log.i(TAG,"SMS Message content" +strMessageBody);`. Nothing happened. When I send an SMS, it only appears on the android messaging app.

Comment: @ThelmaJay Then it's not your Toasts that are broken. You have some other incorrect code. You should either update the question to reflect your new issue, or you should close this question and ask another one.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe tks. I updated it. I am new to android studio and to android I am still trying to understand how to debug in this tool.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the MAIN inside activity tag on AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```